# passing the results of awk command as a parameter

Tags: shell, shell-script

Suppose I have used `awk` to get the value of two different columns:

Say the output is:

abc

def

Now, I want to use both `abc` and `def` as patterns for `grep`, using a pipeline with the previous command. Is there any way to do this?

**For more clarification:**

I have a  pdf file and I am searching for a keyword the file using :

```
pdftotext 'filename.pdf' - | grep 'pattern'
```

Now if any match is found, I want to use the first and second column of the result as parameters for grep in pipeline with the previous command. I can get the first two columns using

```
pdftotext 'filename.pdf' - | grep 'pattern' | awk '{ print $1, "\t"$2 }'
```

Now how will I pass these two values again (2nd time) as patterns after grep command in pipeline with the above one?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Please provide an example.

Comment: I have edited the post. Hope you will understand now @glenn jackman

Answer (score 5):

You could do that with process substitution as follows:

```
grep -f <(awk '{print $1 "\n" $3}' filename) otherfile
```

This will have `grep` read its patterns from a file (the `-f` flag), which in this case is actually the output of the process `awk...filename` which prints the patterns one per line.  Then grep searchs for those patterns in `otherfile`

Though perhaps less efficient if you really want to do it in a pipeline you could do it with `grep` reading its patterns from stdin like

```
awk '{print $1 "\n" $3}' filename | grep -f - otherfile
```

Edit: seeing your question's edit about using grep and then awk, you can let awk do the pattern match for you by doing:

```
grep -Ff <(awk '/pattern/ {print $1 "\n" $3}' <(pdftotext 'filename.pdf' -)) otherfile
```

or as a pipeline:

```
pdftotext 'filename.pdf' - | awk '/pattern/ {print $1 "\n" $3}' | grep -Ff - otherfile
```

Comment: if filename=abc.pdf and otherfile=def.pdf, I have used the following command  grep -f <(awk '{print $1 "\n" $3}' abc.pdf) def.pdf  but getting error saying: grep: Unmatched [ or [^ @Eric Renouf

Comment: @Black that probably means the strings being returned from `awk` are things that look like regular expressions to `grep`.  You can add the `-F` flag to grep to tell it not to interpret the strings as regex, instead they are Fixed strings

Comment: what will be the final shell command if I want to use this in pipeline with the command I stated at last in my post? @Eric Renouf

Comment: @Black see my latest update

Comment: according to you will I apply awk on input first? But I wanted to use the two return values from pdftotext 'filename.pdf' - | grep 'pattern' | awk '{ print $1, "\t"$2 }' to use again (2nd time)  as patterns after grep in pipeline with this same command @Eric Renouf

Comment: @black I'm saying there's no point in doing a grep and piping that to awk because awk can do the pattern matching without grep, so you can skip that step.  Then you can still use the output of that as patterns in a grep command searching another file

Comment: say I have a file file.pdf. and I want to search for "Magic of science" Inside this file both times . Now will I use pdftotext 'file.pdf' - | awk '/Magic of science/ {print $1 "\n" $3}' | grep -Ff - file.pdf, this command or something else, please make me correct if I am wrong. @Eric Renouf

Comment: @black that looks like it should work to me

Comment: I am getting no output. @Eric Renouf

Comment: @black you are using file.pdf as both the first and second file, is that what you intended?

Comment: yes I am using the same file twice @Eric Renouf

Answer (score 4):

Many shells support *command substitution* so that for example

```
p=$(awk '{ print $1,$3 }' filename)
```

captures the output of the command `awk '{ print $1,$3 }' filename` into variable `p`. Note that your `cat` is redundant here: `awk` can read directly from `filename`.

However, I suspect what you really want to do is process *successive* lines of `awk`'s output and parse them into *separate* variables. If that's the case, you can likely do something such as

```
awk '{print $1,$3}' filename | while read -r p1 p2; do grep -F "$p1" otherfile | grep -F "$p2"; done
```

to find lines in `otherfile` that match both fields `$1` and `$3` from `filename`.

Comment: getting error saying: grep: Unmatched [ or [^ @steeldriver

Comment: @Black please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): your current example using `abc` and `def` doesn't contain any special characters such as `[`. You may need to use `grep -F` to enforce fixed string matching rather than regular expression matching.

Comment: I have edited the post. Hope you will now understand my requirements @steeldriver

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using command substitution.

Quoting from [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html):

> Command substitution allows the output of a command to be substituted in place of the command name itself. Command substitution shall occur when the command is enclosed as follows:
>
> `$(command)`
>
> or (backquoted version):
>
> `` `command` ``

Answer (score 0):

You can learn how to use `xargs` to pass and define parameters.

```
cat filename|awk '{print $1,"\n"$3}'|xargs -I {} grep {} somefile
```

`xargs -I {}` replace the parameter with "{}" to let grep use it

Comment: If my filename is abc and I am using cat abc | awk '{print $1,"\n"$3}'| xargs -I {} grep {} def   ,but is not showing any result @Shellmode

Comment: `xarg -I {} ` makes **abc** & **def** both to be "{}", and you can use the "{}" to be the pattern of **grep**.

Exmaple: If you want to find lines in file named test.txt match the pattern abc **or** def. And the pattern is the output of `cat pattern`. You can have a try:

    cat pattern | xargs -I {} sh -c 'grep $1 test.txt' --{}